# Getting an attribute value using Perl XPath

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I'm trying to extract the attribute `id` from `messaggioUtente` on this XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?meta name="GENERATOR" content="XML::Smart/1.78 Perl/5.022001 [MSWin32]" ?>

<messaggiUtenti schemaLocation="messagiUtentiSchema.xsd">
  <messaggioUtente id="1">
    <nome>Prova Evento</nome>
    <email>example@email.com</email>
    <sitoweb>www.example.com</sitoweb>
    <messaggio>Sample</messaggio>
  </messaggioUtente>
</messaggiUtenti>
```

My idea was to use [`XML::XPath`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::XPath) and [`XML::XPath::XMLParser`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::XPath::XMLParser) in this way, but i'm getting an incorrect result:

```
my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => 'newfile.xml');
my $nodeset = $xp->find('//@id'); 

foreach my $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {

        print XML::XPath::XMLParser::as_string($node);
 }
```

The problem is, I'm trying to get the integer value from the id, while this code extract the whole string `id = "1"`.

What's your suggestion to achieve this? My goal is getting the id number and increase it until i get a new unused id for my next `messaggioUtente` value. 
So my code is something like this, but due to the string problem it's not correct.

```
$id = 1;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => 'newfile.xml');
my $nodeset = $xp->find('//@id'); 

foreach my $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {

        my $tempvar = XML::XPath::XMLParser::as_string($node);
        if($node eq $id)
        {
            $id = $id + 1;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I think you want `$node->getNodeText`

Comment: @ikegami: `No such method getNodeText in XML::XPath::Node::AttributeImpl`

Comment: `XML::XPath::XMLParser::as_string($node)` is generally written `$node->toString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element of the nodeset is a [`XML::XPath::Node::Attribute`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::XPath::Node::Attribute) object which has a `getNodeValue` method to get the *value* of the node

The best way to get the next ID in sequence is to find the maximum value of all the `id` attributes and add one to it

It's also probably best to use an XPath expression of `//messaggioUtente/@id` to avoid picking up the `id` attribute of any other element

This code demonstrates. I've addded two more elements to your sample data with `id` values of 2 and 3 to show the functionality better

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use XML::XPath;
use List::Util 'max';

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(ioref => \*DATA);

my $ids = $xp->find('//messaggioUtente/@id');

my $new_id = 1 + max map { $_->getNodeValue } $ids->get_nodelist;

say "New ID = $new_id";

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?meta name="GENERATOR" content="XML::Smart/1.78 Perl/5.022001 [MSWin32]" ?>

<messaggiUtenti schemaLocation="messagiUtentiSchema.xsd">
  <messaggioUtente id="1">
    <nome>Prova Evento</nome>
    <email>example@email.com</email>
    <sitoweb>www.example.com</sitoweb>
    <messaggio>Sample</messaggio>
  </messaggioUtente>
  <messaggioUtente id="2">
    <nome>Prova Evento</nome>
    <email>example@email.com</email>
    <sitoweb>www.example.com</sitoweb>
    <messaggio>Sample</messaggio>
  </messaggioUtente>
  <messaggioUtente id="3">
    <nome>Prova Evento</nome>
    <email>example@email.com</email>
    <sitoweb>www.example.com</sitoweb>
    <messaggio>Sample</messaggio>
  </messaggioUtente>
</messaggiUtenti>
```

#### output

```
New ID = 4
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindness and for explanation, i'll add your solution to my script !  I tried to look at this library's documentation but it was very unclear for me! Thanks again